# Selenium scripts no working in Selenium Server and Selenium Html Runner

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

I've been trying to use `Selenium` to run some scripts recorded in `Selenium IDE`. I've followed every step of [this blog](http://internetdevels.com/blog/jenkins-selenium-testing), and I got stuck with this error:

**Command:**

```
java -jar selenium-html-runner-3.0.1.jar -htmlSuite *firefox https://www.google.com "testegglg/Suite.html" "testegglg/result.html"

Unable to find the HTML runner. This is normally because you have not
downloaded
    or made available the 'selenium-leg-rc' jar on the CLASSPATH. Your test will
    not be run.
    Download the Selenium HTML Runner from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and
    use that in place of the selenium-server-standalone.jar for the simplest way of
    running your HTML suite.
```

So, I tried with the html runner and got this:

```
java -jar selenium-html-runner-3.0.1.jar -htmlSuite *firefox https://www.google.com "testegglg/Suite.html" "testegglg/result.html"

Multi-window mode is longer used as an option and will be ignored.
  Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320) on port 20688
  Only local connections are allowed.
  Jan 27, 2017 9:37:03 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
  Jan 27, 2017 9:37:03 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
  2017-01-27 09:37:03.864:INFO::main: Logging initialized @787ms
  2017-01-27 09:37:03.908:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
  2017-01-27 09:37:03.916:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.h.ContextHandler@1d296da{/tests,null,AVAILABLE}
  2017-01-27 09:37:03.922:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@815b41f{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:21835}
  2017-01-27 09:37:03.923:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @846ms
  2017-01-27 09:37:03.924:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Stopped ServerConnector@815b41f{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:21835}
  2017-01-27 09:37:03.925:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Stopped o.s.j.s.h.ContextHandler@1d296da{/tests,null,UNAVAILABLE}
  Jan 27, 2017 9:37:03 AM org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher mainInt
  WARNING: Test of browser failed: *googlechrome
  java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.determineSuiteUrl(HTMLLauncher.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.runHTMLSuite(HTMLLauncher.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.mainInt(HTMLLauncher.java:245)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.main(HTMLLauncher.java:273)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.pollPort(PortProber.java:154)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.pollPort(PortProber.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.determineSuiteUrl(HTMLLauncher.java:174)
    ... 3 more
  Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.Socket.bind(Socket.java:644)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.pollPort(PortProber.java:146)
    ... 5 more
```

Note: -port [number of the port] doesn't work.

I just want to run the scripts i had recorded in the IDE so i can use it with `Jenkins`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the way to launch Selenium scripts, recorded in Selenium IDE, I would recommend using Taurus, that is able to execute Selenium actions and can be integrated with such CI tool as Jenkins. The step by step instructions are described in this post - https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-automate-jmeter-and-selenium-testing .